# Spring JUnit JPA Transaction not rolling back

Tags: spring, jpa

I am trying to test my DAO that uses JPA EntityManager to fetch and update entities. I have marked my unit test as Transactional and set the defaultRollback property to false. However, I don't see my transactions rolling back at the end of the test when throwing a rune time exception. The data is getting persisted in the DB. Here is my unit test code along with spring configuration. I am clearly missing something but havent been able to identify what.
Btw, the transaction is RESOURCE_LOCAL in the persistence.xml

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:spring/test-jpa.xml"})
@TestExecutionListeners(
{   DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class,
DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class
})
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback=false)
@Transactional
public class JpaTests {
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManage em;

    @Test
    public void testTransactionQueueManager() {
        Object entity = em.find(1);
        //code to update entity omitted.
    entity = em.merge(entity);
    em.flush();
        throw new RuntimeException
    }
}
```

Spring Configuration

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jpa.driverclassname}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jpa.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jpa.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jpa.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="${jpa.persistenceunitname}"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.OpenJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionary"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean> 

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
```

Comment: How did you verify that the transaction didn't rollback? Did the database have updated values?  Which database are you using, if it mysql what storage engine?

Comment: yes, I am using SQL Server 2008 and the database has updated values. Btw, my JPA provider is IBM Websphere Thin client

Comment: I had a problem with transactions not rolled back, fixed it by TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration seems fine. 
There could be different reasons for the unexpected commit, maybe a datasource with autocommit mode or a non transaction compliant database (mysql with MyISAM ?)

Did you check this thread [Why are transactions not rolling back when using SpringJUnit4ClassRunner/MySQL/Spring/Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827770/why-are-transactions-not-rolling-back-when-using-springjunit4classrunner-mysql-s) ?

Comment: or this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3128111/spring-jta-jpa-dao-integration-test-doesnt-rollback?

Answer (score 0):

@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback=false)

might be the culprit. Try defaultRollback=true, that should rollback the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `rollbackFor` may help, it's a common pitfall.

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class)
```